# replace words in xml

Tags: python, xml

I have a function that where I enter 2 words to replace some words in xml file however when I use this code nothing get replaced and I don't know where is the problem.

```
def xml_changer(x,y):
    with open('wf_PWX.xml', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        tree = ET.parse(f)
        root = tree.getroot()
        for elem in root.getiterator():
            try:
                elem.text = elem.text.replace('pwx',x)
                elem.text = elem.text.replace('hq0001_ABS_TYPES', y)
                elem.text = elem.text.replace('ABS_TYPES', x)
            except AttributeError:
                pass
    tree.write('output.xml', encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: I suggest that you debug your code by adding `print()` statements or using the debugger in your editor. You should inspect the value of `elem.text` after each replace to check that it was you expect. Then check that `tree` looks the way you expect after the loop finishes. Also check the documentation for `replace()` to make sure you are using it correctly.

Comment: share the input and the output xml please

Answer (score 0):

Fairly certain your tree.write() statement should be inside your with open block. When your with open block closes the file is closed as well, without saving any changes.